# submit blank numeric text box as null no 0 in php

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to insert text value of type=number(numeric only text box) to insert into mysql db. Corresponding field in db is set as unique and null(default)... but when submit form it send 0 instead of NULL. due to this I get db error of duplicate item when send other record with numeric textbox blank.
here is my form code:

```
<form action="save_new_pir.php" id="newpir" name="new_pir" method="POST">  
<input type="number" min="1" name="file_no" id="file_no"></input> 
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" class="logbtn"/> 
</form>
```

**validation file code is:**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{  
$file_no = test_input($_POST["file_no"]);  
}
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);  
$data = stripslashes($data);  
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);  
$data= mysql_real_escape_string($data);  
return $data;
}
```

save setting file is: pir_no is the field giving duplicate item error in my sql.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pir_detail(pir_sr, **pir_no,** pir_type, pir_dor, pir_fin_year, pir_related, file_status, file_no, pir_status, pir_progress, online_status, pir_remark)
   VALUES(' ', '$pir_no', '$pir_type', '$pir_dor', '$pir_fin_year','$pir_related', '$file_status', '$file_no','$pir_status', '$pir_progress', '$online_status', '$pir_remark')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{    
header('Location: pir_reg_form.php?pir_no='.$pir_no);        
} 
else
{
$error= $conn->error;    
echo "Error:".$conn->error."<br>";
echo '<a href="pir_reg_form.php">Back to NEW PIR Form</a>';
}
```

Comment: any fix for this problem? file no. is numeric value to be inserted in db and it is unique or null(if blank)

Comment: Could you just check if the value of the input file_no is zero then change it to null before saving it in the database?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do when using the [low-level SQL server driver](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: That `test_input` function is not only completely inadequate, it's wrong and will irreparably mangle and damage any user input that passes through it.

Comment: i have tried using 'NULLIF('$file_no','')' in my sql query and function test_file_no($fileno)
    {
            //$file_no = $fileno;
            if($fileno==0)
            {
            $fileno=NULL;
            return $fileno;
            }
            else {return $fileno;} in validation file before passing to sql. but still getting same duplicate key pir_no error. i dont know why.  help.